# Combining localization and base change properties of the module of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an algebra over a ring $R$.  Let $\mathfrak P$ be a prime of $A$ with preimage $\mathfrak p$ in $R$.  We have the localized ring $A_{\mathfrak p}$, which further localizes to $A_{\mathfrak P}$.

Let $\Omega_{A/R}$ be the module of differentials of $A$ over $R$.  There are two very nice properties of $\Omega_{A/R}$.  First, there is base change: if $R'$ is an $R$-algebra, then

$$\Omega_{A/R} \otimes_R R' = \Omega_{(A\otimes_R R')/R'} \tag{1}$$

Second, there is localization: if $S \subset A$ is multiplicatively closed, then

$$S^{-1}\Omega_{A/R} = \Omega_{S^{-1}A/R} \tag{2}$$
or in other words, $\Omega_{A/R} \otimes_A S^{-1}A = \Omega_{S^{-1}A/R}$.

I want to combine these properties to say that $(\Omega_{A/R})_{\mathfrak P} = \Omega_{A_{\mathfrak P}/R_{\mathfrak p}}$ as $A_{\mathfrak P}$-modules.  I haven't seen this property written down before, but I believe it is true.  On account of the transitivity of localization, we have

$$(\Omega_{A/R})_{\mathfrak P} = ((\Omega_{A/R})_{\mathfrak p})_{\mathfrak P} = (\Omega_{A/R} \otimes_R R_{\mathfrak p})_{\mathfrak P} \stackrel{(1)}{=} (\Omega_{A \otimes_R R_{\mathfrak p}/R_{\mathfrak p}})_{\mathfrak P} = (\Omega_{A_{\mathfrak p}/R_{\mathfrak p}})_{\mathfrak P} \stackrel{(2)}{=} \Omega_{(A_{\mathfrak p})_{\mathfrak P}/R_{\mathfrak p}} = \Omega_{A_{\mathfrak P}/R_{\mathfrak p}}$$

Is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Fine for me too.